# How to fix clipped output from R postscript function?

Tags: r, graphics, postscript

The output from the `postscript` function is generating clipped output. See the legend on the right side of the figure below, the last legend entry should read SBW-25. I've tried changing the `width` argument to `postscript` but this has had no effect. I've also tried manually editting the bounding box in generated postscript but this also has had no effect.
[image]

Comment: You say, "See the legend on the left side of the figure below..." Do you mean the right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wihtout a reproducible example, it is hard to diagnose, but here are some things to try.

If you are viewing the postscript in [GSView](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/), you probably just need to increase paper size.  Click Media -> A0 (or something suitably big).

If you save to a different format (PDF, PNG, whatever), do you get the same effect?

If all else fails, try manually changing the legend position with

```
p + opts(legend.position = whatever)
```